# Get X and Y coordinates of each cell from a table and transform into a new table in sql server

Tags: sql-server, matrix, coordinates, unpivot

I'm trying to build a query for a matrix table which has a schema like this:

```
ID           1           2           3
----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
1           13          32          55
2           30          75          129
```

I want to get the position of a cell according to its coordinate (row number and column number) to create a new table that has the fields row_num, col_num and value

In the example given, this query should return:

```
row_num col_num value
------- ------- -----------
1       1       13
2       1       30
1       2       32
2       2       75
1       3       55
2       3       129
```

The query must obtain the value of each cell and return its position X and Y.
I have tried different approach without success. I tried to use `UNPIVOT`, but it is not showing me the correct information.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

UPDATED:
I added a column whit row number

Comment: You should know that tables in a relational database are unsorted by nature, meaning that the row_num is meaningless, unless you have some column to order by.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to *unpivot* the data and generate row number. Here is one way using `CROSS APPLY`

```
select Row_number()over(partition by col_num order by ID) as row_num,
       col_num,
       value
from yourtable 
cross apply(values ([1],'1'),([2],'2'),([3],'3')) tc (value,col_num)
```

To do this using `unpivot` try this way

```
select Id,col_num,value
from Yourtable
unpivot
(
  value
  for col_num in ([1], [2], [3])
) u;
```

Comment: How I can use `UNPIVOT` correctly, instead of  `CROSS APLLY`?

Comment: I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you do have a column that specifies the ordering, you can do the calculation as:

```
select dense_rank() over (order by ??) as row_num,
       v.col_num, v.val
from matrix m cross apply
     (values (m.col1, 1), (m.col2, 2), (m.col3, 3)
     ) v(val, col_num);
```

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  The `??` is for whatever column specifies the ordering.  If it is already `row_num`, then you don't need the `dense_rank()`.

Comment: I Added a column with the row number called ID

Comment: I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

**For the Updated Question**

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,[1] int,[2] int,[3] int)
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,13,32,55),
(2,30,75,129)

Select A.ID as row_nu,
      ,B.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
               values (1,A.[1])
                     ,(2,A.[2])
                     ,(3,A.[3])
             ) B (col_num,value)
 Order by B.col_num,A.ID
```

Returns

```
row_num col_num value
1       1       13
2       1       30
1       2       32
2       2       75
1       3       55
2       3       129
```

> **EDIT - As requested UnPivot**

```
Select ID as row_num ,col_num,value
 From  @Yourtable 
 UnPivot (Value for col_num in ([1], [2], [3]) ) B
 Order By 2,1
```

Comment: Thank you! but, how I can use UNPIVOT correctly, instead of CROSS APLLY?

Comment: I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @JotaPardo Happy to help, but in all fairness, Prdp and Gordon were spot-on for the original question.